# Evaluating the integral $\int\frac{x^{1/6}-1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I evaluate the following integral $$\int\frac{x^{1/6}-1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}}dx.$$

Comment: Hint: $$ x^{\frac{2}{3}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^{\frac{1}{6}} - 1) $$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just expand $x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}=x^{1/2}(x^{1/6}-1)$. After cancellation, you're left with $\int x^{-1/2}dx=2\sqrt{x}+C$.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $u={x}^\frac 16\implies u^6=x\implies 6u^5\,du=dx$:
$$\therefore 6\int\frac{(u-1)u^5}{u^4-u^3}\,du=6\int\frac{u^5}{u^3}\,du=6\int u^2\,du=\frac{6u^3}{3}+c=2\sqrt{x}+c$$

Comment: I'd say it like this: $u = x^{1/6}$, so $u^6 = x$ and then $6u^5\,du = dx$. ${}\qquad{}$